# Create http and https endpoint using camel in the same server with jetty

Tags: java, ssl, https, apache-camel, jetty

I am trying to create HTTP and HTTPS endpoint in one of my web service.
I want secure few endpoints with HTTPS and other endpoints with plain HTTP.

I am using the below code to do the same.

```
    public void configure() {
        configureJetty();
        configureHttp4();
        //This works with configuring Jetty
        from("jetty:https://0.0.0.0:8085/sample1/?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
                .to("file://./?fileName=out.csv");
        //This url does not working with the configuring the jetty with configure jetty this works.
        from("jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8084/sample2/?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
                .to("file://./?fileName=out2.csv");
    }

private void configureJetty() {
        KeyStoreParameters ksp = new KeyStoreParameters();
        ksp.setResource("./trustStore.jks");
        ksp.setPassword("someSecretPassword");
        KeyManagersParameters kmp = new KeyManagersParameters();
        kmp.setKeyStore(ksp); kmp.setKeyPassword("someSecretPassword");
        SSLContextParameters scp = new SSLContextParameters();
        scp.setKeyManagers(kmp);
        JettyHttpComponent jettyComponent = getContext().getComponent("jetty", JettyHttpComponent.class);
        jettyComponent.setSslContextParameters(scp);
    }
```

The https works fine with this setup but the http endpoint does not work.
If I remove the method call to configure Jetty the HTTP endpoint works.
How I can configure both in the same server?
I can not use spring boot but only plain camel components.

I have created a github repository with the sample code. You can find it here. [sample code](https://github.com/irudra/camel-test)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can

- create two distinct instances of jetty component, one for plain http, the other for https.
- register each of them with a specific alias ("jetty" and "jettys")
- use appropriate alias in your endpoint uris "from("jettys:...")

CDI Example:

```
@Produces
@ApplicationScoped 
@Named("jetty")
public final JettyHttpComponent createJettyComponent1() {       
    return this.configureJetty(false);
}

@Produces
@ApplicationScoped 
@Named("jettys")
public final JettyHttpComponent createJettyComponent2() {       
    return this.configureJetty(true);
}  

private void configureJetty(boolean ssl) {
   ...
    JettyHttpComponent jettyComponent = new JettyHttpComponent();
    if (ssl) {
        jettyComponent.setSslContextParameters(scp);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Awesome, Thank you. The Jetty component could not be initialized in my version as it was an abstract class. So I used JettyHttpComponent9 and added it to the camel context.